# Set image as background for pages in Liferay 6.2 GA2

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme

I want to set a background image for pages in *Liferay 6.2 GA2 CE* under `diffs/custom.css`. I have written below code:

```
body {

    @include background-image('/images/flowers.jpg');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

The image is kept under `diffs/images` folder but image is not set after deploying the theme. So can anyone please guide me how to set background image for pages in Liferay?

And is there any reference book or blog for developing a theme right from the scrach? If so please provide the link. It would be great help as I'm new to Liferay.

main.css

@import url(base.css);

@import url(application.css);

@import url(layout.css);

@import url(dockbar.css);

@import url(navigation.css);

@import url(portlet.css);

@import url(extras.css);

@import url(custom.css);

Comment: Did you check the `main.css` result in the browser? How does the reference to `flowers.jpg` look like?

Comment: This is _not_ the compiled `main.css` in your browser (it should not contain any `@import` statements). So either you specified the `main.css` from your source directory, or you have a SASS - compilation error. Check you log in that case.

Comment: thanks for the solution. its working fine now.